# Converting values of an index to columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

If have a long dataframe, that features a two column multiindex and one column with values. I think this is the best way to represent data in pandas (tidy), but I'd like to convert it to a format that excel is capable of working with. The current format has too many rows. I start out with pandas in the first place, because i have about 6 GB of .csv data and excel won't do the job. A lot of it is cropped, so I hope the output is more manageable.

```
                                VALUE
DATE                    ID      
2005-01-01 00:00:00     222     3.8
2005-01-01 01:00:00     222     3.7
2005-01-01 02:00:00     222     3.2
2005-01-01 00:00:00     201     3.1
2005-01-01 01:00:00     201     3.7
2005-01-01 02:00:00     201     3.2
...................................
```

The desired format for .csv export would look as follows:

```
                        201     222     ....
DATE                          
2005-01-01 00:00:00     3.1     3.8     ....
2005-01-01 01:00:00     3.7     3.7     ....
2005-01-01 02:00:00     3.2     3.2     ....
```

So in short, I'd like to convert every index value "ID" to a seperate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column `VALUE` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df['VALUE'].unstack()
```

If `df` is `Series` then use:

```
df1 = df.unstack()
```

Comment: I'm amazed that it's that easy.

Comment: After trying it out, the right way to use it seems to be df1 = df.unstack('VALUE')

Comment: @Harper - If `df` is Series, then `df1 = df.unstack()` should working

Comment: Yes, that is also an option, but `df1 = df['VALUE'].unstack()` does not. It returns a key error.